# Landing API Requests

Tags: design, api-design, microservices

I think this question is simple, but I'm not often designing APIs and so I haven't confronted it: **How far should we go to adhere to the single responsibility principle?**

Let's say we are implementing an RESTful CRUD API composed of microservices. For the creation action, we need to significantly restructure incoming data before storing it in our database. Should we do that in the same microservice that inserts the data? Or should we have one microservice format the data, and another add the data to our database.

If we should split the format & insert action, should we also slap the formatted data into an unstructured store like an Azure blob, or have the services talk directly to each other?

Kind of case by case, but I'd love to hear smart designer's thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

A Micro-service is responsible for a Domain of Behaviour. Its a standalone vertical slice of functionality. It is responsible for managing its own data and any internal format changes. To be clear a Micro service is a: `Interface <-> Business Logic <-> Persistence Layer`. Where:

- *Micro* means (*in a no we really really mean this because no one actually understands modular design*) that the Business Logic is highly cohesive. Requiring access to the same data, in the same representation, at the same point in the life-cycle of that data.
- *Service* means that you can only communicate with it through the `Interface`. No back doors, no connecting to the backing db, no accessing its cache...

> **How far should we go to adhere to the single responsibility principle?**

The problem is the level of analysis. You are jumping up and down throughout your question.

The short answer is that it is a rule of thumb, does applying it have the desired results?

What are the desired results? Less code? Less Testing? A fast system? A robust System? Figure that out and you can judge what is right for your problem.

Without more details I hazard to give direct advice on where to place the file translation.

More specifically it sounds like you are attempting to horizontally partition a service. This way leads to pain. The service needs to reach all the way up to its interface and all the way down to its own long-term state in such a way that it is separate and autonomous.

> we need to significantly restructure incoming data

If the service was not restructuring the data then what exactly is the service offering that is different from a blob/record service? Is your service offering more behaviour? Is it restricting behaviour?

> before storing it in our database

Who's database? The database is the mechanism by which one or more services persist their state. Each Service should have its own separate state. Otherwise these are not independent services, but a single and not very micro service.

> If we should split the format & insert action, should we also slap the formatted data into an unstructured store like an Azure blob, or have the services talk directly to each other?

As above, the services should communicate through their service interface. If the service interface includes files, or a data store that is fine. However access via these mechanisms must enforce the business logic.

Generally speaking it is very hard to get Azure Blob storage  to enforce anything but Blob Storage semantics. Which circles back to the question, *What exactly is your service offering that the Blob Service is not? Or what is your service not offering that a Blob service will permit?*

I have seen this sort of interface done via some RDBMS systems, but to call it easy to maintain or extend... well they were not very readable at all.

**Presentation API**

Depending on your system sometimes it makes sense to separate the micro-service APIs from your clients.

A good example might be a desktop application which has a slow release cadence in comparison to the daily releases to the back-end micro-services.

It might make sense to use a Presentation Service that sits on your own system (and can be updated daily) that provides a rich API to the client (to make the client efficient) and manages the complex API's and interactions required to get the job done amongst your menagerie of micro-services.

This allows you to change and completely rescape the micro-service environment behind the scenes.